# Why mouseout animation is not working properly?

Tags: jquery, css-animations, keyframe

I have tried the following. It worked in mouse in but doesn't work properly on mouse out.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes animborder {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
}

@keyframes animborder {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
}

.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
.section-title::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(87, 107, 181, 0.45);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.section-title:hover::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  -webkit-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -moz-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out;
  -o-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out;
  animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="section-title">Check our Videos</h1>
```

I have followed In and out keyframes for mouse over and mouse out but it didn't worked and the effect animated on page refresh. Could you please guide me where I am doing wrongly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is achievable using only CSS animations. I am assuming that CSS transitions do not fulfil your use case, because (for example) you want to chain two animations together, use multiple stops, iterations, or in some other way exploit the additional power animations grant you.

You must need to use two different animations with jquery like below.

```js
$(".section-title").hover(
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('out').addClass('over');
    },
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass('over').addClass('out');
    }
);
```

```css
@-webkit-keyframes animborder {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
}

@keyframes animborder {
  0% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes animborder_out {
  0% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
}

@keyframes animborder_out {
  0% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 100%;
    top: auto;
  }
  50% {
    height: 8px;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
  100% {
    height: 100%;
    width: 8px;
    top: auto;
  }
}

.section-title {
  margin-bottom: 45px;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 15px 30px;
}
.section-title:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: auto;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 8px;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(87, 107, 181, 0.45);
  z-index: -1;
  transition: 0.7s ease-in-out;
}
.section-title.over::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  -webkit-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: animborder 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
}

.section-title.out::before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px;
  -webkit-animation: animborder_out 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  -moz-animation: animborder_out 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  -o-animation: animborder_out 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
  animation: animborder_out 0.7s ease-in-out forwards;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1 class="section-title">Check our Videos</h1>
```